# My table view is displaying nothing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a table view for the first time, and the information does not get displayed.  This is what I did:
1. Drag a table view onto my view controller (story board)
2. brought up Assitent editor and schedule.h file.
3. ctrl drag from the view controller to the schedule.h file to add propertry.
4, named it mTable.
5. added code   (on view did load)

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
mTable.delegate=self;
```

then 6. added methods

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// functions to handle table
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface cSchedule : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *tableData;

    __weak IBOutlet UITableView *mTable;

   }

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    mTable.delegate=self;

}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// functions to handle table
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you're formatting this I assume?

Comment: @Tanner, one line of code looks okay. :)

Comment: Yikes, that's an ugly post.  Anyway, by text-searching for "datasource", I noticed you didn't mention connecting the datasource for the table view to the view controller containing those datasource methods.  This is probably the #1 cause for "my table view shows nothing".

Comment: I was going to format, but seeing as it's just been posted and he has reasonable rep I asked the question... watch this space!

Comment: Also, down voters take note: formatting mixing lists and code blocks is (as far as I can tell) broken.  I've tried before, and just now on this post.  The two don't play nice together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set Your `UITableViewDataSource`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

    mtable.delegate = self;

    mtable.dataSource = self;

}
```

Comment: He having outlet property for tableview as mTable only. Thats why i put mTable.

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling your table view where the data source is.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    mTable.delegate=self;
}
```

Should be

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    mTable.delegate=self;
    mTable.dataSource=self;
}
```

The delegate is what the table view uses when an action is preformed (when it's touched for exampled), while the data source is responsible for the actual data that is presented (like `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). So your methods are not getting called right now, and the table thinks it has no data to display.